# Find a polygon intersecting a “Big” Polygon inside a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I try to find a polygon intersecting a "Big" polygon inside a MongoDB document.

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects) I know that

> For $geoIntersects, if you specify a single-ringed polygon that has an area greater than a single hemisphere, ... , $geoIntersects queries for the complementary geometry.

If the "Big" polygon is used in the query - you can specify a custom [MongoDB CRS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#intersects-a-big-polygon) to avoid that:

```
$geometry: {
   type: "Polygon",
   coordinates: [ <coordinates> ],
   crs: {
     type: "name",
     properties: { name: "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326"     
   }
}
```

But how can I handle it, if it's the other way around, the "Big" polygon is stored in the MongoDB ? Simple use case for the described scenario: *Find all countries a polygon intersects*